# Partial upgrade (PATCH) in Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, http-headers

I'm trying to implement a API with a Symfony2 backend.
To support PATCH and partial update of entities I'm trying to workaround the fact that Symfony2 will make attributes NULL when they're not included in the form.

I found this workaround over at https://gist.github.com/makasim/3720535 but I'm not sure where to implement this or call it in my controllers.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the cookbook-entries for the Form-component: "[How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)":

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Do your stuff
    $builder->addEventSubscriber(new PatchSubscriber ());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the latest versions of Symfony2 do not require the mentioned workaround as the native support for partial binding on PATCH request was merged https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/7849